# How to trigger SMS using API in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, cloudpage, sms

When someone submits the cloud page form, I need to send Thank You SMS with their name using API. how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In order to trigger a text message, you will have to interact with Salesforce Marketing Cloud’s REST API using the /sms/v1/messageContact/{id}/send route:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
try {

//API authentication  
var authEndpoint = "";  //provide authentication endpoint
var payload = {
        clientId: "",  //provide Client Id
        clientSecret: ""  //provide Client Secret
    };
var url = authEndpoint + "/v1/requestToken";  
var contentType = "application/json";


   var accessTokenRequest = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload));
   if(accessTokenRequest.StatusCode == 200) {
        var tokenResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenRequest.Response[0]);
        var accessToken = tokenResponse.accessToken;
   }

//make a call using the messageContact route
var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];
var smsEndpoint = "";  //provide rest endpoint
var smsPayload = {
    "mobileNumbers": [
    ""  //pass phone number
    ],
    "Subscribe": true,
    "Resubscribe": true,
    "keyword": ""  //provide KEYWORD
};
var smsUrl = smsEndpoint + "/sms/v1/messageContact/xxxxxxxxx/send";  //provide message API key
  
var sendSMS = HTTP.Post(smsUrl, contentType, Stringify(smsPayload), headerNames, headerValues);

} catch (error) {
    Write(Stringify(error));
}  

  
</script>
```

In the above script, you will need to provide your endpoints, ClientId and ClientSecret (all three can be found in Setup > Apps > Installed Packages). You will also need to insert the message Api Key, the keyword and pass the recipient’s phone number.

For more details and a tutorial, see here: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/12/20/trigger-sms-text-messages-using-server-side-javascript/